# IBM Watson Classifier ID and multiple classifying

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

With the IBM Watson Visual Recognition API, how do you know the Classifier ID when we create the train? How do you do multiple classifying?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please see if this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577484/watson-visual-recognition-classify-against-multiple-classifiers-in-java

Comment: Using curl you could do this to get a list `curl -u "<Username>":"<Password>" \
-X GET \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition-beta/api/v2/classifiers?version=2015-12-02"` this will give you a response scroll to the top to see yours

Answer (score 0):

1. The `classifier_id` is part of the response you get when creating a custom classifier.
2. To use multiple classifiers you just need to send the `classifier_ids` query parameter with a comma separated list of classifier id (e.g `classifier_ids=foo_123,fruits_934,bar_345`)

Take a look at the [API Reference](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/) to get some examples of how to create and use a custom classifier.